# I am using Java to get some records from elastic search by dynamically generating a query in my code. The query takes a string

Tags: string, elasticsearch, java

I have a JAVA code that fetches some records from ES. The JAVA code is as follows :

```
public Map<String, Object> getRiskDetailsFromEventIds(final String eventId) {
    try {
        String elasticBaseUrl = elasticsearchConfig.getEsUrl();
        String esIndexName = elasticsearchConfig.getHitsIndex();
        String endpointUrl = elasticBaseUrl + "/" + esIndexName + "/_search";
        String queryTemplate = IOUtils.toString(ESRepositary.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
                "querytemplates/hits_search_event_es_query_template.json"), Charset.defaultCharset());
        String query = String.format(queryTemplate, eventId);
        return getResultsFromElastic(endpointUrl, query);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
    }
}
```

My hits_search_event_es_query_template.json looks something like this

```
{

  "_source": [
   "hitNumber","eventId","hitScore","severityLevel","priority","hitType.typeCode","targetOwner","hitType.search","recommendedAction","referralId"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "eventId": ["%s"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size" : "50"
}
```

Now, this takes a String. My eventId is : "A,B,C,D"

The String that I need to pass to the query template should be : "A","B","C","D"
Can someone help me break down my String this way or if someone can help me modify my ES query to utilise what I have.

Comment: Sorry, but your question seems a bit unclear to me. What String are you talking about and what is the JAVA Api you are using currently?

Comment: Let me make my question a bit clearer. I'll edit the same.

Comment: Still its not clear to me. You need to pass a dynamic event Id to your query? Is that right. What type of String value it holds? `"A,B,C,D"` or `"A","B","C","D"`

Comment: It holds "A","B","C","D"

Answer (score 0):

Getting a List of the eventIds, I am able to do the following :

```
String eventId = eventIds.stream().map(event -> "\""+event+"\"").collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

where eventIds is the List

Also I have changed my query as below :

```
{

  "_source": [
   "hitNumber","eventId","hitScore","severityLevel","priority","hitType.typeCode","targetOwner","hitType.search","recommendedAction","referralId"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "eventId": [%s]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size" : "50"
}
```

This gives me the required query which I need.